# python : atlassian.errors.ApiValueError: No space or no content type, or setup a wrong version type set to content, or status param is not draft

Tags: python, api, confluence, confluence-rest-api, atlassian-python-api

I am using confluence API (using python)to update an **existing confluence page** but I am facing the below error:

> atlassian.errors.ApiValueError: No space or no content type, or setup a wrong version type set to content, or status param is not draft and status content is current

Strange thing is I was able to update the page before may be 10 times but its suddenly throwing an error. maybe i am missing something?

Can anyone please suggest what is missing. I am using below snippet:

```
confluence = Confluence(url=confluence_url,username=userid,password=password)

status = confluence.update_page(page_id, title, pagecontent)

pprint(status)
```

Comment: Are you able to log into confluence in the browser and view/edit the page?

Comment: yes i can login and able to edit the page

Answer (score 2):

I see the same error because my pagecontent contains `<DC>` in it and in HTML `<` and `>` need to be escaped.

Seems the third param of `update_page` require a valid html string.

You can use it `escape` method in python if you are using python 3.4+

```py
from html import escape
from atlassian import Confluence


confluence = Confluence(url=confluence_url,username=userid,password=password)

status = confluence.update_page(page_id, title, escape(pagecontent))

pprint(status)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , yes i found that there was some issues with my html content which i was trying to load

Comment: how to add web page in confluence using api?

Answer (score 0):

remove character \n,
need to use a list of strings

Comment: Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and attach more information to your answer. Currently, your answer isn't understandable and helpful

Comment: remove \n from where ?